# How can I collect all the configuration files I modified in a system?

Tags: configuration

Since the first installation of my system I modified various config files in /etc and I customised my system.

Copying the whole /etc for storage in a safe location before reinstalling/upgrading would slow down and potentially damage a new install, therefore how can I collect all and only the modified files?

Comment: Typically very hard to do properly. Looking at my own `/etc` I see plenty of files that are fairly recent and that I didn't change myself (likely due to automatic updates and a few recent installs). Not mentioning things that are links to files outside of `/etc` (like most `/etc/systemd` services). Personally I keep a shadow of `/etc` files I change (`/etc/hosts`, for instance), so they get backed up with my stuff when I do backups. I can also edit them with my favorite graphical editor and just `sudo cp` them when they are ready.

Comment: @xenoid That sounds like a decent solution - maybe not what OP is looking for, but still a solution. Could you post it as an answer?

Comment: It looks like my question is answered partially in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72746/get-diff-changes-between-original-files-installed-with-apt-and-current-files and in the links posted there -> there is no simple way to do what I asked